# Drawing dust using json . How to draw the key data in dust

Tags: javascript, json, dust.js

This is the data:

```
 var json=   [
        {
            "key1": "val1"
        },
        {
            "key2": "val2"
        },
        {
            "key3": "val3"
        }
    ]
```

How can I draw the data both  **'key1', 'key2','key3'**  and **'val1'
,'val2' ,'val3'** to draw it in dust?

If the object is like

```
var address =   {
    "a": "addressr",
    "c": "city",
    "s": "state",
    "z": "zip" 
}
```

and if I know the keys already I can draw like `{address.a}` to get the address.

Comment: i want to draw in using  dust .

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve my problem for right now **(please explain if there is another direct way)**

```
var newjson = [];
for(var key in json)
 {
    var arr     =   json[key]; 
    var value   =   arr[Object.keys(arr)[0]]; 
    var keys    =   Object.keys(arr)[0] ;
    var len         =       newjson.length;
    newjson[len]    =       {
                "k":keys,
                "v":value
                    }   
 }
```

and i padd newjson to the dust file and draw as

```
{#newjson}
{k}-----{v}
{/newjson}
```

the output will be

> key1------val1 key2------val2 key13------val3